# How to insert data from other tables in a third table in frontend project with vue

Tags: vue.js, join, axios, frontend

I have 4 tables, one for users, one for students, one for family of students, and the other one for the people that make registrations called "Auxiliar" in the code.  I need to create the relation between familiar and students into a third table. There, i'd put through an input the students's ID, familiar's ID and the auxiliar's ID because she/he is the person with the authorization or token to make the registration. In the backend everything goes perfect but I have mistakes with the code in frontend. I got the error 500. Here's the code:

this is part where is the form where I send the input

```
enter code here
```

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="processEstudianteFamiliar">
   <label>Ingrese el Id del estudiante</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="asignacion.estudiante"/>
        <label>Ingrese el Id del familiar</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="asignacion.familiar"/>
        <label>Ingrese el Id del auxiliar</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="asignacion.registra"/>
        <button type="submit">Asignar</button>
</form>
```

**Then this is the script**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: "EstudianteFamiliar",
    data: function () 
    {
        return {
            asignacion:{
                    estudiante: "",
                    familiar: "",  
                    registra: ""
            }, 
                    loaded: false,
        } 
    }, 

 methods:{
        verifyToken : async function() {
            return axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/refresh/",
                {refresh: localStorage.getItem("token_refresh")}, 
                {headers:{}}
            )
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("New access token");
                localStorage.setItem("token_access", result.data.access);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.$emit("logOut");
            })
        },
        processAsignarFamiliar: async function() {
            if (localStorage.getItem("token_access") === null ||
                localStorage.getItem("token_refresh") === null){
                    this.$emit('logOut');
                    return;
                }
                await this.verifyToken();
                let token = localStorage.getItem("token_access");        
             
            console.log(this.asignacion,2)
            console.log(token)
            
            axios.post(
                "http://127.0.0.1:8000/estudianteFamiliar/",
                 this.asignacion,
                {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`} }
            )
                .then((result)=>{
                    let dataEstudianteFamiliar={
                        token_access: result.data.access,
                        token_refresh: result.data.refresh
                    }
                    console.log(result.data)
                    console.log(this.asignacion),
                    this.$emit('completedEstudianteFamiliar', dataEstudianteFamiliar);
                    
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Error: Falló la asignación del familiar del estudiante");
                });
            }, 
            created: async function () {
                this.processEstudianteFamiliar();
            } 
    }  
}
```

I'm doing something wrong in the frontend because when i test in postman the backend runs ok and create the relation in the database. I haven't found out what it is. The error send me to this in the backend and I guess i'm making the relation wrong in the code.

```
token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')[7:]
auxValido = validateAuxiliar(token, request.data['asignacion']['registra'])
```

**the key error is the ['asignacion']**

Thank you so much I'd apreciate your helph.

Comment: did you check postman request body and browser network tab paylod equal?

Comment: yes, I did and they are equal

Comment: @Lakmi you were right, the body were not equal and I thought they were.  Thank you so much.